# How to draw a line in a UIview, when I push button? (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, drawing

I began to study Xcode and I can't understand how to draw a line in a view, when I push button
I have this code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{        
 CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetLineWidth(con, 5);
 CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
 CGFloat componen [] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
 CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(space, componen);
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(con, color);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(con, 0, 0);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(con, 100, 100);
 CGContextStrokePath(con);
 CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
 CGColorRelease(color);

}
```

This code draw a line when I start my application, but I wanna to start this code when I push button with my parameters(x1,x2,y1,y2). 
I created a function  like this

```
- (void)drawLine
{   
    CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(con, 5);
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat componen [] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(space, componen);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(con, color);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(con, x1, y1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(con, x2, y2);
    CGContextStrokePath(con);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    CGColorRelease(color);

}
```

But it can't draw

How to do this?

Comment: what do you mean with pushing a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `drawRect:` so that it decides whether it should draw a line or not:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self.drawLine) {
        [self drawLineWithContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        self.drawLine = NO;
    }
}
```

When the button is tapped, have your view controller set your view parameters and tell the system to refresh your view:

```
- (IBAction)doDrawing:(id)sender {
    self.drawView.drawLine = YES;
    self.drawView.x1 = 20.0;
    self.drawView.x2 = 200.0;
    self.drawView.y1 = 10.0;
    self.drawView.y2 = 350.0;
    [self.drawView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I add a line for UIView is pretty simple.

```
UILabel *line = [[UILabel alloc]init];
line.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.5];
line.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1);
[self.view addSubview:line];
```

And then you can press button to control its visible property.

Is that OK for your question?

Answer (score 0):

the
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { }
method calls by the system.
before the view load it will call by the system and draw the content.

so if you change the drawing content after the view load you have to ask the system to call drawRect method. so you have to call the relevant view's setNeedsDisplay method.

[myView setNeedsDisplay];

thanx